# For each row, how to sum values for columns start with same string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Edit: the column names indeed start with more than 1 character, but with a sep='_', it's more like AAA_BBB, AAA_DDD, BBB_EEE, BBB_FFF, ...

Thanks for the groupby solutions!

---

I have a pandas dataframe like this (borrowed from another question):

```
df =

C1    C2    T3  T5
28    34    11  22
45    100   33  66
```

How can I get a new dataframe, with sum of columns that have the same "starting string", e.g. "C", "T" ? Thanks!

```
df =

C     T  
62    33    
145   99
```

Unfortunately I have to deal with this structure of dataframe, and there are about 1000 columns in the dataframe, looks like A1,A2,A3,B1,B2,B3, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` with `axis=1`

OP was vague about the general characteristics of the column names.  Please read the various options to determine what is more appropriate for your specific case.

#### `callable` version #1

Assuming your column prefixes are single characters...

```
from operator import itemgetter

df.groupby(itemgetter(0), axis=1).sum()

     C   T
0   62  33
1  145  99
```

When you pass a `callable` to `pandas.DataFrame.groupby`, it maps that callable onto the index (or columns if `axis=1`) and lets the unique results act as the grouping keys.

---

#### `callable` version #2: Roll Our Own

A little more convoluted but should be robust for more than just single character prefixes.  Also, uses no imports.

```
def yield_while_alpha(x):
    it = iter(x)
    y = next(it)
    while y.isalpha():
        yield y
        y = next(it)

def get_prefix(x):
    return ''.join(yield_while_alpha(x))

df.groupby(get_prefix, axis=1).sum()

     C   T
0   62  33
1  145  99
```

Same exact idea but using `itertools` instead

```
from itertools import takewhile

df.groupby(
    lambda x: ''.join(takewhile(str.isalpha, x)),
    axis=1
).sum()

     C   T
0   62  33
1  145  99
```

---

#### `pandas.Index.str.extract`

Or we don't have to use a `callable`

```
df.groupby(df.columns.str.extract('(\D+)', expand=False), axis=1).sum()

     C   T
0   62  33
1  145  99
```

Answer (score 4):

Use,

```
 df.groupby(df.columns.str[0], axis=1).sum()
```

Output:

```
     C   T
0   62  33
1  145  99
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative using `MultiIndex`:

```
df.columns = [df.columns.str[0], df.columns]
df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()
```